# After history.back() , hisytory.pushState does not increment history length

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Just like this picture

[image]

write something like below:

```
history.pushState(null,null,"./abc");
history.back();
console.log(history.length);
history.pushState(null,null,"./abc");
console.log(history.length);
```

I test it in chrome and firefox, both seems have this problem, I do not know why

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the concept of `history.length`

The History.length read-only property returns an integer representing the number of elements in the session history, including the currently loaded page.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/length

According to the concept , If you click `back` button then go forward again. the history.length would not change, because history.length is the number of elements in the session history.